# Access IP Camera Teledye in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

How do I access my IP Camera stream?

Code for displaying a standard webcam stream is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How do I do the same exact thing but with the IP Camera?

My system:

- Python 3.6.5
- Opencv 3.2.0
- Teledyne Dalsa Genie Nano G3-GC11-C1920 Camera

You can use video capture Object as

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture("IP:PORT/video")
```

This is the information about the camera connection:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is the last sentence (*you can use video capture Object as ...*) supposed to be the answer? If you can use that, what is the problem?

Comment: You can use rtsp or http protocol to grab stream, its simple: `cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.X.X/...")`

Comment: I tried it that way but OpenCV didn't start capturing it with the camera

Comment: Python return this error 
`warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779)
warning: http://192.168.1.10/1 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:780)`

Answer (score 0):

I  have been trying to do the same but my camera is the Genie Nano-C1950.

I was not able to connect with the camera using the Opencv cv2.VideoCapture(0).

I searched for some alternatives and found:

- [Harversters](https://github.com/genicam/harvesters) to use with Python
- [Sapera LT SDK](https://www.teledynedalsa.com/en/products/imaging/vision-software/sapera-lt/) to use with C# .NET or Visual Basic

Where the Sapera LT SDK is provided by Teledyne DALSA and they have an example in C# and Visual Basic to stream images from the camera.

I was able to call a .exe file generated by the C# .NET application with Python.

To generate the executable I used a console sample code from Sapera SDK. Which Teledyne Dalsa provided. The ideia behind the sample code is to connect to the camera and show on the screen the live video coming form the camera itself. I got the parts I needed to access the camera and did not need the IP address or anything, since the Sapera SDK sample code would list all the Teledyne Dalsa cameras connected to my PC.

And Harversters make use of the GeniCam standard to do image acquisition. By using python and knowing the IP address you can connect to the Genie Nano camera.

I am no expert but if you need anything just let me know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).